# How should I version my project dlls so that when I copy them from one solution to another, the new solution always uses the latest version

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have two solutions in different folders. Here is an example of the file structure:

- C:\VSProjects\FooSolution\
- C:\VSProjects\FooSolution\DllLibrary\
- C:\VSProjects\FooSolution\FooProject\
- C:\VSProjects\FooSolution\FooProject\FooProject.csproj
- C:\VSProjects\MyUtilitiesSolution\MyUtilities.sln
- C:\VSProjects\MyUtilitiesSolution\MyUtilities\MyUtilities.csproj

FooProject needs to reference the MyUtilities.dll. So, after making changes in MyUtilities, I manually copy its dll from MyUtilities\bin\Release\ into FooSolution's DllLibrary folder.

In FooProject, I add references to MyUtilities.dll in the DllLibrary folder.

How does this setup sound so far?

The problem I have is that FooProject keeps on getting confused and uses old versions of the MyUtilities dlls. I just want FooProject to always use the dlls that are in DllLibrary. How can I set things up so FooProject always uses the version of the dll that is in the DllLibrary folder?

Comment: also you only need to add the reference one time!

Comment: Why isn't the "MyUtilities" project part of the FooProject Solution and referenced as a project, then the latest dll will be built and included whenever you build "FooProject".

Comment: Because MyUtilities is shared by other solutions. Each solution is a completely different project (i.e. completely different business). There is no reason to keep them in the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the post build command line option from the project property. use the XCOPY command to copy from the specific folder to another..

option will be available -> select the project in VS and properties -> build events

hope it helps...

Comment: Doing the copy is not the problem. I am happy to do that manually. The problem is that Visual Studio doesn't recognise that the dll has changed and keeps using an old version of the dll.

Comment: If you want to update the dll always you should add those project into your solution and add reference of those projects not dlls

Answer (score 0):

How does the reference in FooProject.csproj looks something like? You can try fiddling with how reference is specified, e.g. I'd change

```
<Reference Include="MyUtilities, Version=1.0.XX.YY, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=blahblahblah, processorArchitecture=x86">
  <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\VSProjects\FooSolution\DllLibrary\MyUtilities.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

to

```
<Reference Include="MyUtilities">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\VSProjects\FooSolution\DllLibrary\MyUtilities.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```